# layer system in fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am designing business card designer application with fabric.js canvas in this application i need a system for managing objects  z-index and for that i created two buttons for sending selected object in back and front its working fine but in all my designs i have a background image on which all text and objects placed when i send a object back it send back under that BG image how can stop that i mean i want that BG image to always in last position

[preview of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVOGH.jpg)

**Code i am using now to send object in front and back**

```
 var selectedObject;
      canvas.on('object:selected', function(event) {
        selectedObject = event.target;
      });

      var sendSelectedObjectBack = function() {
        canvas.sendToBack(selectedObject);
      }

      var sendSelectedObjectToFront = function() {
        canvas.bringToFront(selectedObject);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Option**

> Use canvas.setBackgroundImage(obj)

**Second Option**

*If you don't want to set backgroundImage*

You can do it after you send back your selected object, you need to again send your BG object to back.

Try this.

```
var sendSelectedObjectBack = function() {
    canvas.sendToBack(selectedObject); //this will send selected object to back.
    // Now loop through all your obj
    canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
    // get your background with id or any other property
        if (obj && obj.id.indexOf('BG_') > -1) {
            canvas.bringToBack(obj, true); // this will send your BG always at back
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://images2.alphacoders.com/147/147320.png', function(img) {
    var oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 00,
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height
    });
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(oImg).renderAll();
});

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    radius: 50,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'yellow'
}))
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    height: 150,
    width:150,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'green'
}))

var sendSelectedObjectBack = function() {
  selectedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(selectedObject)
  canvas.sendToBack(selectedObject);
  canvas.deactivateAll();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

var sendSelectedObjectToFront = function() {
  selectedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(selectedObject)
  canvas.bringToFront(selectedObject);
  canvas.deactivateAll();
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js"></script>

<button onclick='sendSelectedObjectBack();'>Send back</button>
<button onclick='sendSelectedObjectToFront();'>Bring Front</button>
<canvas id='c' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
```

Set your background using `canvas.setBackgroundImage(obj)`, then it will stay ion back all the time.